# Marginal likelihood / model evidence through densities

Tags: bayesian, model, likelihood, marginal-distribution

Lets say I have two datasets $y_0,...,y_T$ and $y^*_0,...,y^*_T$ with like 300 observations (point estimates) each and the observations are like normally distributed.

$y$ is observed from the "Real Generating Process" while $y*$ are the estimates from Model M*.

I am struggling to find a way to calculate the marginal likelihoods straight from theses distributions. Shouldn't it be possible to estimate the probability of $M*$ is being the "Real Generating Process" given data $y$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $y_{i}^{*}$, $i=1,...,T$ are predicted values from a model rather than the estimates of the paramters in the model? If so then say you entertain the  model $Y_{ij}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i1}+..+\beta_{p}x_{ip}+\epsilon_{i}$ for the $i^{th}$ person, as the DGP (data generating process) for your observed data $\{y_{i}\}_{i}$. Then of course you can test the hypothesis

$H_{0}:E[Y_{i}]=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i1}+..+\beta_{p}x_{ip}\hspace{50pt}i=1,...,N$

subject to an assumption like $\epsilon_{i}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, all independent - i.e. with an F-test. Say your observed F statistic has p-value 0.01, then as you may know, this is supposed to be interpreted that given $H_{0}$ is true, and subject to the distributional assumption on the errors, that less than 1% of the time (if we repeated our data collection over and over) would we expect such a good model fit. Is this what you were getting at mathematically?

This tells you your model is pretty good, but is it *the* true DGP? Well clearly to suggest there is some random number generator out there adding random Gaussian noise onto some linear function is clearly ludicrous. This is obviously a philisophical point but an imortant one. See these links here for a far more eloquent explanation than I can give;

[What is the meaning of "All models are wrong, but some are useful"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57407/what-is-the-meaning-of-all-models-are-wrong-but-some-are-useful)

[In regression analysis what's the difference between data-generation process and model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/in-regression-analysis-whats-the-difference-between-data-generation-process-and)